# R: divide values in rows dataframe by the maximum value in that row

Tags: r, dataframe, max, row

I would like to do a simple thing in R. I have a dataframe with 1000s of rows and several columns, and would like to divide each value in the dataframe by the maximum value in its corresponding row.

An example of a dataframe:

```
x <- data.frame("condition_1" = c(2,4,6,8,10), "condition_2" = c(1,4,5,3,2), "condition_3" = c(1,5,9,3,12))
row.names(x) <- c('gene_1', 'gene_2', 'gene_3', 'gene_4', 'gene_5')
```

The dataframe looks like this:

```
> x
       condition_1 condition_2 condition_3
gene_1           2           1           1
gene_2           4           4           5
gene_3           6           5           9
gene_4           8           3           3
gene_5          10           2          12
```

Now, I solved my problem with below code:

```
xnorm = NULL
for (row in 1:nrow(x)){
  tmp = x[row,] / max(x[row,]) 
  xnorm = rbind(xnorm, tmp)
}
rownames(xnorm) = rownames(x)
```

The output looks like this:

```
> xnorm
       condition_1 condition_2 condition_3
gene_1   1.0000000   0.5000000       0.500
gene_2   0.8000000   0.8000000       1.000
gene_3   0.6666667   0.5555556       1.000
gene_4   1.0000000   0.3750000       0.375
gene_5   0.8333333   0.1666667       1.000
```

As you can see, this works. However, my solution seems way too elaborate, and I am sure there must be some clean R-solution for this. Can anyone point me into the right direction for a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `base R`, it can be done with `vectorized` `pmax`

```
x/do.call(pmax, x)
```

-output

```
#       condition_1 condition_2 condition_3
#gene_1   1.0000000   0.5000000       0.500
#gene_2   0.8000000   0.8000000       1.000
#gene_3   0.6666667   0.5555556       1.000
#gene_4   1.0000000   0.3750000       0.375
#gene_5   0.8333333   0.1666667       1.000
```

---

Or with less efficient method using `apply`

```
t(apply(x, 1, function(u) u/max(u)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
newx <- x %>% rownames_to_column('id') %>%
  pivot_longer(-id) %>%
  group_by(id) %>% mutate(value=value/max(value,na.rm=T)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from=name,values_from=value) %>%
  column_to_rownames('id')
```

Output:

```
       condition_1 condition_2 condition_3
gene_1   1.0000000   0.5000000       0.500
gene_2   0.8000000   0.8000000       1.000
gene_3   0.6666667   0.5555556       1.000
gene_4   1.0000000   0.3750000       0.375
gene_5   0.8333333   0.1666667       1.000
```